# How to remove duplicate object in List with double key

Tags: c#

I have list object's. But it has *duplicate records* for **2** key - `itemId` and `itemTypeId`. How do I *remove duplicates* from the list?

I tried `GroupBy` - but it can only use *one key* at a time.

```
public class TestObject
{
        public string Name;
        public int itemTypeId;
        public int itemId;
        public int id;
}

List <TestObject> testList = new List<TestObject>();

TestObject to1 = new TestObject();
TestObject to2 = new TestObject();
TestObject to3 = new TestObject():

to1.id = 1;
to1.itemId = 252;
to1.itemTypeId = 1;
to1.Name = "to1";

to2.id = 2;
to2.itemId = 252;
to2.itemTypeId = 1;
to2.Name = "to2";

to3.id = 3;
to3.itemId = 252;
to3.itemTypeId = 2;
to3.Name = "to3"

testList.Add(to1);
testList.Add(to2);
testList.Add(to3);

var result = testList.GroupBy(x=>x.itemId).Select(g => 
g.First()).ToList();
```

Actual Result :

`to1` and `to3`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can group with multiple fields using the following syntax, grouping will filter out the duplicate entries:

```
var testListNoDups = testList.GroupBy(x => new {x.itemId, x.itemTypeId})
                                  .Select(x => x.First())
                                  .ToList();
```

Comment: I would suggest doing a `SelectMany`/`Take(1)` combo, rather than `Select`/`First`. There are situations where the latter will fail, yet the former will succeed.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I'm sorry, but when can `Select/First` (potentially) *fail*? Since we `GroupBy` we can be quite sure that each group `x` has *at least* `1` item, so `First()` always succeeds.

Comment: Yes, I agree when it immediately follows a `GroupBy`, but when it doesn't then it can fail. That's why my suggestion is a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to modify *existing* `testList`, you can try `RemoveAll`:

```
 HashSet<Tuple<int, int>> keys = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>();

 testList.RemoveAll(x => !keys.Add(Tuple.Create(x.itemId, x.itemTypeId)));
```

Here we try to add next key to `keys` and in case of failure (i.e. key exists in `keys`) we remove the item from `testList`